# QGIS composer Draw grid selection

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to change programmatically using python the grid on the map composer of QGIS.

Does anyone knows the syntax for this operation?

[image: grid selection]

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found is to dynamically modify the xml of the composer using the following code.

```
 
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
p = tree.parse("...\\print2.qpt")
for node in p.findall('Composition/ComposerMap/ComposerMapGrid'):
    if node.attrib['intervalX']:
        node.set('intervalX','ValueOfX)
    if node.attrib['intervalY']:
        node.set('intervalY', 'ValueOfY')
tree.write("..\print2.qpt")`
```